# Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server - httpd.service failed for redmine

Tags: linux, centos, apache-httpd

I am trying to install redmine on centos but getting an error with apache.

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-06-03 13:16:54 +04; 1min 45s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 17406 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 17404 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 17404 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 03 13:16:54 localhost httpd[17404]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
Jun 03 13:16:54 localhost httpd[17404]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
Jun 03 13:16:54 localhost httpd[17404]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Jun 03 13:16:54 localhost httpd[17404]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Jun 03 13:16:54 localhost systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 03 13:16:54 localhost kill[17406]: kill: cannot find process ""
Jun 03 13:16:54 localhost systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 03 13:16:54 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jun 03 13:16:54 localhost systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jun 03 13:16:54 localhost systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

Comment: There is an other process (i.e. an other webserver) running on your machine already using port 80. You need to find out [which process](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/), define if this is normal/expected and then take a decision regarding which webserver you should use.

Comment: `(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80` some process is already using port `80` clear it, and try to restart.